How to remove physical device from Android Studio?
Is it possible to remove the physical device connected to Android Studio?
Virtual devices can be deleted in the Device Manager, but there is no option to delete devices of the Type "Physical".

Physical devices should only be visible while they are connected via USB, unless you performed e.g. a WiFi pairing. If you did you should be able to revert this on command-line using adb command.
